# How transforming xts object on data.frame in R (quantmod package)

Tags: r, time-series, xts, quantmod

I would want to transform xts object to data.frame format in R.

However, I just solved.
Now, I'll share with you.

Example:

#### Loading packages

`library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)`

#### Getting SP500 index

`SP500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", 
from = as.Date("2002-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-12-31"))`

A GSPC archive is generated.

`head(GSPC)
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2002-01-02   1148.08   1154.67  1136.23    1154.67  1171000000       1154.67
2002-01-03   1154.67   1165.27  1154.01    1165.27  1398900000       1165.27
2002-01-04   1165.27   1176.55  1163.42    1172.51  1513000000       1172.51
2002-01-07   1172.51   1176.97  1163.55    1164.89  1308300000       1164.89
2002-01-08   1164.89   1167.60  1157.46    1160.71  1258800000       1160.71
2002-01-09   1160.71   1174.26  1151.89    1155.14  1452000000       1155.14`

`class(GSPC)
"[1] xts" "zoo"`

#### How solve it?

*Tibble will transform xts format.*

`SP500 <- as.tibble(GSPC)`

`A tibble: 6 x 6
  GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
1   1148.08   1154.67  1136.23    1154.67  1171000000       1154.67
2   1154.67   1165.27  1154.01    1165.27  1398900000       1165.27
3   1165.27   1176.55  1163.42    1172.51  1513000000       1172.51
4   1172.51   1176.97  1163.55    1164.89  1308300000       1164.89
5   1164.89   1167.60  1157.46    1160.71  1258800000       1160.71
6   1160.71   1174.26  1151.89    1155.14  1452000000       1155.14`

#### Where is the each of row name? It's there!

`head(rownames(SP500))
[1] "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" "2002-01-07" "2002-01-08" "2002-01-09"`

*The output it is a date format.*

`DATE <- rownames(SP500)
DATE %<>% as.Date()`

#### Pipe command (%>%) ever saves us!

*Creating a new variable and ordering column names*

`SP500 %<>% mutate(DATE = DATE) %>%
  select(DATE, GSPC.Open:GSPC.Adjusted)`

#### Then..

`# A tibble: 6 x 7
        DATE GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
       <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2002-01-02   1148.08   1154.67  1136.23    1154.67  1171000000       1154.67
2 2002-01-03   1154.67   1165.27  1154.01    1165.27  1398900000       1165.27
3 2002-01-04   1165.27   1176.55  1163.42    1172.51  1513000000       1172.51
4 2002-01-07   1172.51   1176.97  1163.55    1164.89  1308300000       1164.89
5 2002-01-08   1164.89   1167.60  1157.46    1160.71  1258800000       1160.71
6 2002-01-09   1160.71   1174.26  1151.89    1155.14  1452000000       1155.14`

I hope this helps.
See you.

Comment: Flagged. Not a question. Maybe you should work on the documentation section of stackexchange? (And it's even not a correct answer to the implicit question in the title.)

Comment: You're right. I'll do it!

Answer (score 4):

The way this is normally done is:

```
library(quantmod) # also pulls in xts and zoo
getSymbols("^GSPC")
DF <- fortify.zoo(GSPC)
```